# The type or namespace name 'XmlDocument' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to parse an xml document using the following:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument ();
doc.LoadXml (myXMLstring);
```

I get the error:

> The type or namespace name 'XmlDocument' could not be
>   found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

..even though I have
using System.Xml;

I'm not sure what an assembly reference is. I'm using Xamarin Studio. I see there are several folders for references. In the references folder for the base project I don't see an entry for System.Xml

But in individual platforms I do see System.Xml in there.

What can I do to get this error line to clear?

Comment: Add : using System.Xml;  If still issue, then from menu Project : Reference : Add Reference : .Net tab : System.Xml

Comment: What is the project type of xml2? Some project types just don't allow such references to be added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I posted on the Xamarin forums: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/46042/missing-assembly-reference-for-system-xml#latest

Use `XDocument.Parse(string)` to accomplish this from your Portable Class Library.

XDocument is included in the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace so you will need to add the using directive for that namespace in your class.

The reason that you cannot access `XmlDocument` from a Portable Class Library (PCL) is due to the fact that a PCL will only expose APIs that are supported on all platforms that the PCL targets. Windows Phone 8 does not support XmlDocument, and so this isn't available in the PCL. Windows Store apps support XmlDocument but it is available in a different namespace (`Windows.Data.Xml.Dom`). So for this reason `System.Xml.XmlDocument` cannot be used from the PCL. Anything else provided through the `System.Xml` namespace in the PCL is fine to use.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following steps:

> 1. Under the solution explorer on the left, right click on ***References*** and select ***Edit References***
> 2. Go to ***.Net Assembly*** or ***All*** Tab and pick the ***System.Xml***
> 3. Click OK.

Comment: Hello, thank's for the suggestion. However this is what I see when I do as you suggest: http://ohiovr.com/xfer/assembly.JPG I don't see an add button

Comment: Go to All Tab and check..if you find it select it and then click Ok.

Comment: in .Net Assembly Tab you can see Browse Button. Try find System.Xml in your computer and Add to your project in this way.

Comment: Actually I seem to have acumlated dozens of these System.Xml.dll files. If I just copy one of them willy nilly and add it to my root folder I can add it in the way that you mentioned. However now I get the error "/Users/Scott/Projects/xml2/xml2/CSC: Error CS1703: An assembly `System.Xml' with the same identity has already been imported. Consider removing one of the references (CS1703) (xml2)"

Comment: if you already have this reference, try removing and re-adding it.

Answer (score 1):

Check if System.Xml is referenced in your project. Unfortunately I don't know how to do it in Xamarin Studio. In Visual Studio if you expand your project you will see *References* directory. If System.Xml is not there you can easily add it there by right-clicking on *References* and selecting *Add Reference*. After that you will be able to use XmlDocument class and entire content of System.Xml assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to source

```
using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;
```